# Secret Word Game

Tags: java

I was assigned to create a guessing game where you are given a secret word in asterisks and have 5 tries to guess the correct word.  They enter in a letter at a time and those letters are revealed in the word.  Unlike hangman each turn counts and not just every time they pick a letter that’s not in the word. The class only requires a default constructor Here is my code so far and here is the driver: http://pastebin.com/35T9B4wM

```
public class SecretWord {
private String secretWord;
private String hintWord;
private int numberOfTurns;

public SecretWord() 
{
    this.secretWord = "fruit";
    this.numberOfTurns = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<secretWord.length();i++)
    {
        hintWord+="*";
    }   
}
public String getSecretWord()
{
    return this.secretWord;
}
public String getHintWord()
{
    return this.hintWord;
}
public int getNumberOfTurns()
{
    return this.numberOfTurns;
}
public void setSecretWord() 
{
    this.secretWord = "fruit";
}
public void setHintWord()
{

}
public void setNumberOfTurns(int i)
{
    this.numberOfTurns = 5;
}
public void guessLetter() 
{

}

}
```

I'm just not understanding what should go in the accessors or mutators.  Or in the guessLetter variable where whenever the letter is found in the secret word, then that letter replaces that asterisk in the hint word.
Here is a list of instructions that may help.

- This class has three instance variables
- secretWord: the word the user
  has to guess
- hintWord: the word with the guess letters revealed
- numberOfTurns: keeps track of the number of guesses
- This class only requires a default constructor
- You set the secret word
- Number of turns to a default value of 0
- The hint word is constructed using asterisk (*) for every letter that’s in the secret word
- Accessors for every instance variable
- Mutators for every instance variable CHECK FOR VALID VALUES!

Comment: What seems to be the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I'm stuck and really have no idea on what to put inside of the mutators (valid values).  Also I'm stuck on what to put inside of the guessLetter variable where it puts the correct guessed letter in place of an asterisk.  @gonzo

Comment: Well the mutators you have coded currently look fine. You just want to validate the value before setting it to any of your instance variable. For example, on your `setNumberOfTurns`, what type of values would not be valid here? Hint: Can we have a negative number of turns?

Comment: And also, I'm not sure if I need to put anything in the setHintWord mutator.  @gonzo

Comment: Well based on your instructions, you need to use the default constructor. You have defined your own constructor so you probably want to get rid of that. Getting rid of that, though, deletes your setup for setting `hintWord` to asterisks . You probably want to move that logic to your `setHintWord ` mutator.

Comment: Add validation logic for your `setSecretWord` mutator. Think about what cases do not make sense when setting this `secretWord` and catch those cases. Update your question with all of these code changes and then we can go from there. :)

Comment: I'm not really sure if I need validation for setSecretWord since I'm going to be the one setting the word and not a user.  Or am I confused with that part? @gonzo.

Comment: Then yeah that should be fine. If a user was going to set `secretWord`, we would probably just want to do a quick check and make sure no numbers or punctuation is in the string before setting it to `secertWord` since it is a hangman game. Change the mutator, though, to take in a `String` similar to what you have done in `setNumberOfTurns`.

Comment: Alright thanks for that.  My last problem is just the guessLetter variable.  My professor recommends toCharArray but I really don't know what to do.  For example, if user guesses u for the hidden word "fruit", it would display **u**  @gonzo.

Comment: Okay. Lets work this in steps. First your `guessLetter` method probably needs to take in a letter as a parameter? After we have this letter what would would we do? We need to check it against what? After we do this check what would we need to update if we find any matches? Try this out first and do as much as you can and then I can jump in and help you out. :)

Comment: Would something like this work: for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess) { 
                    found = true;                   
                    correctLetters[i] = guess;      
                }
            } @gonzo

Comment: Added an answer to help with the logic. Let me know if you are still having issues or if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you are pretty close on the logic. You just have to update your `hintWord` after. Something like this should do the trick.

```
hintWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){ 
    if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess){  //Check if we found anything
        //found = true; We do not need this variable since we already know if we found something 
        correctLetters[i] = guess;
    }
    hintWord += correctLetters[i];
}
```

Just make sure your `correctLetters` is set correctly in the beginning. You can set it in your `setHintWord`. Like this:

```
public void setHintWord(){
    correctLetters = new char[secretWord.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<secretWord.length();i++)
    {
        hintWord+="*";
        correctLetters[i] += '*';
    }
}
```

If you do not want to keep track of another instance variable (since your instructions say to only use 3) you can do something like this with a temporary `String`.

```
public void guessLetter(char guess){
    String tempHintWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){ 
        if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess){  //Check if we found anything
            //found = true; We do not need this variable since we already know if we found something 
            tempHintWord += guess;
        }else{
            tempHintWord += hintWord.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    hintWord = tempHintWord;
}
```

Comment: I figured everything out.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChristianN feel free to accept my answer if it helped you figure everything out. Thanks.